# Firebase update error: The behavior for date objects stored in Firestore is going to change and your app may break

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react-native with Firestore 5.2.0 but the error is regarding the update of Firestore to 5.0.4.

The error is:

The behaviour for date objects stored in Firestore is going to change and your app may break. To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling other cloud Firestore methods:

```
const firestore= firebase.firestore();
const settings ={ /*your settings */ timestampInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);
```

Can anyone help me out how can I get out of this error?

Thanks

[Firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GScw.png)

Comment: Did you check out some of the other questions mentioning that error? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+behavior+for+date+objects+stored+in+Firestore+is+going+to+change+and+your+app+may+break

Comment: Thankyou @frank...Yes, I have checked all the other questions that were posted earlier...but none of them gave the answer that is related to the error..Can you please help me out?

Comment: Sorry, but that seems very unlikely. The message is quite specific, so I'd expect those questions to be about the same message. The message also is quite explicit about what you need to do. What have you already tried?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've found a solution for it....

Comment: Good to hear Kalyani. If you can post that as an answer, including the code changes you made, that answer might be helpful to others who are confused by the error message.

Comment: sure, thanks @ frank

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I am creating a fitness app in which daily steps count should be stored. Can you please suggest me how to store the daily step count datewise. I've searched many blogs and docs but didn't get any solution. It would be great if you can help me...
Thank you

Comment: It's hard to give blatant advice about NoSQL data models, because they depend on your use-case more than anything else. So the question is how you want to access the data, not how you want to store it. For some general advice, see this great article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Answer (score 5):

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCPW020BADuNGvwOPhad4XSq_UYVK3OSxM",
  authDomain: "firestorecrud-b08be.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://firestorecrud-b08be.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "firestorecrud-b08be",
  storageBucket: "firestorecrud-b08be.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "742054197796"
});

const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};

firebase.firestore().settings(settings);
```

Just add the above two statements in your code where you are configuring your firebase/firestore code.

Answer (score 0):

## Update as of March, 2019

### For versions 5.8.0 or above

You should not be getting this error anymore.

In [Version 5.8.0 - Jan 17, 2019](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) there were some breaking changes introduced:

> **BREAKING**: The `timestampsInSnapshots` setting is now enabled by default. Now, timestamp fields read from a `DocumentSnapshot` will be returned as `Timestamp` objects instead of `Date`. Any code expecting to receive a `Date` object must be updated.

**Note:** As stated in [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Firestore#Firestore), `timestampsInSnapshots` is going to be removed in a future release so make sure to remove it altogether.

### For older versions (5.7.2 and below)

This should do the work:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
```