# Unable to set firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }) in App

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I trying to add this statement to my app to forget the known warning:

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK...

I've wrote:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';

export default class App extends React.Component {
      componentWillMount() {
        const config = {
          apiKey: '...',
          authDomain: '...',
          databaseURL: '...',
          projectId: '...',
          storageBucket: '...',
          messagingSenderId: '...'
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };

        firebase.firestore().settings(settings);
      }
```

This is the way it's suggested by many, like this answer:

[Firebase update error: The behavior for date objects stored in Firestore is going to change and your app may break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479679/firebase-update-error-the-behavior-for-date-objects-stored-in-firestore-is-goin)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479679/firebase-update-error-the-behavior-for-date-objects-stored-in-firestore-is-goin)

I do what it's suggested here but Im unable to get out of this error...

> Error: FirebaseError: Unknown option 'timestampsInSnapshots' passed to
>   function settings(). Available options: host, ssl, credentials

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of the newest Firestore e.g. version (7.14.0): The setting 'timestampsInSnapshots: true' is no longer required and should be removed.