# Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I follow the document of firebase, but I can not connect to firebase.

Does anybody face this issue?

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

My code :

- `index.js`

  ```js
  var admin = require("firebase-admin");
  var serviceAccount = require("./key/serviceAccountKey.json");
  admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://sampleLink.firebaseio.com",
  });
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");

  var db = admin.firestore();
  var data = {
      name: "Los Angeles",
      state: "CA",
      country: "USA",
  };

  // Add a new document in collection "cities" with ID 'LA'
  var setDoc = db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set(data);
  setDoc;
  ```
- `package.json`

  ```
  {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
      "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
      "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
      "start": "npm run shell",
      "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
      "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "firebase": "^5.7.3",
      "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
      "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
  }
  ```
- `console`

  ```
  tktktk:functions dev$ node index.js
  Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail

  The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
  AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
  To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
  following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:

  const firestore = new Firestore();
  const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
  firestore.settings(settings);

  With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as
  Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also
  need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:

  // Old:
  const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
  // New:
  const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
  const date = timestamp.toDate();

  Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a
  future release, the behavior will change to the new behavior, so if you do not
  follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
  ```

My env is below:

```
$ firebase --version
6.3.0
$ node -v
v8.12.0
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Comment: To get rid of that long warning, add a line `firebase.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479679/firebase-update-error-the-behavior-for-date-objects-stored-in-firestore-is-goin. I'm not sure about the warning about `FIREBASE_CONFIG` though. What do you mean with " I can not connect to firebase"?

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for the advice. It works to get rid of the long warning.
But I still can not save the data because of missing FIREBASE_CONFIG.

Comment: I am facing this issue more than one month, still can not do any hello world thing.

Answer (score 11):

That `FIREBASE_CONFIG` warning hints that the path to the `JSON` is missing (or wrongful).

Either setup `FIREBASE_CONFIG`, as it demands - or  setup `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) and then run `gcloud auth application-default login`; then you could use `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` instead of `admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)`.

Answer (score 8):

The proper way to run a cloud function locally is via the Functions shell (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator). If you want to run it directly like `$ node index.js`, then you have to set the required environment variables yourself, or otherwise `firebase-functions` is going to complain.

However, note that the above message is just a warning. Your code is running despite that. If you're not seeing any data written to Firestore, that's probably because you're not handling the promise returned by the Firestore `set()` method.

Comment: sir could you please help with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964566/how-to-properly-initialize-firebase-functions-test-using-cloud-function it seems similar

Answer (score 8):

For me, the problem was that line:

`const functions = require('firebase-functions');`

I just deleted it from *index.js*. I don't use Firebase Cloud Function anymore but I forgot to remove that line.
This is where my problem was coming from.

So maybe you too imported this package in a file that don't need it.

Comment: This was a cause of problem for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue.
[Turns out it has to do with Node version 10](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/437) 
I removed Node 10 and went back to Node 8 and everything worked like a charm...

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();
```

Just hit

```
 firebase deploy --only functions
```

in Node v8.

Comment: The asker says they're using Node v8.12.0

Answer (score 2):

About you problem, just now Thanks to your code i was able to fix my problem.

What i do:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount) });

const db = admin.firestore();
```

Im using a Cloud Firestore db, not a real time db, so i dont send the second argument in the **initializeApp**, i just put the config of the db in the environment file.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig : {
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    authDomain: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    databaseURL: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    projectId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    storageBucket: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    messagingSenderId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    measurementId: 'XXXXXXX'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```js
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "private_key_id": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "private_key": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "client_email": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "client_id": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "auth_uri": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "token_uri": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "took from Firebase Generated Private Key"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://test-dia.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to remove the warning as of 2021 is to add `firebase-functions-test` to your dev-dependencies, and call it in your jest config like so:

```js
// jest.preset.js
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();
// ...
```

Read more about testing in "offline mode" here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a Cloud Function locally and want to use cloud authentication and database, eg.

Steps:
1 - Go to your Firebase console and copy your credentials data as JSON, for example:

```
{
      "apiKey": "<YOUR-API-KEY>",
      "authDomain": "<YOUR-authDomain>",
      "databaseURL": "<YOUR-databaseURL>",
      "projectId": "...",
      "storageBucket": "...",
      "messagingSenderId": "...",
      "appId": "..."
}
```

2 - On your project folder, save this as JSON file. 'my_credentials.json' for example.

3 - Run Function Locally: (note the cat)

> $ FIREBASE_CONFIG=$(cat my_credentials.json) npm run local

Note (!):
Add the 'local' script to your package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
   ...
   "local": "npx functions-framework --target=<YOUR-APP-NAME> --signature-type=<YOUR-FUNCTION-CALL-METHOD-EXAMPLE-http>"
 },
```

Comment: Extra: put all together on script/local package.json:
     "local": "FIREBASE_CONFIG=$(cat credentials.json) npx functions-framework --target=app --signature-type=http"

Answer (score -1):

Try using this version dependencies (in `package.json`) with node v8.

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~7.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.1"
}
```

*It worked for me.*