# Calculate time difference within cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, timestamp

In my Cloud Firestore database, always a user is registered, the database stores the time the event occurs:

```
const p = usersReference.add({ 
    ...,
    registerTime: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
    ...
});
```

My goal is to create another cloud function that gets a user as input and returns if there is at least 5 days since the user was registered:

```
export const get_user_timeleft = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        //useless part of the function...       
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                //Here I know that documentSnapshot.data().registerTime 
                //returns whatever is saved in the database.
                //How can I return true or false if there's been 5 
                //or more days since the user registered?
                response.json(TRUE of FALSE);
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        response.json(error);
    });

});
```

---

Clearly I can call `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` again and try to subtract them, but I don't even know the type it is. In the past I've managed to use is as a `Date`, but since Firebase is saying that `Date` will be deprecated, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Do you have one document by user?

Comment: I didn't understand what you asked, but the function to get a user from the database works fine, there are a lot of users in the database to test and they all have a timestamp registerTime in their documents.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear: I imagine that there is one document by user where you store the timestamp of the user's registration. Is this assumption corrrect?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood yet. There is the main collection `users`, then there are a lot of (randomly generated) ids and each of these ids represent an user, which contains information fields `{ name (string), ..., registerTime(timestamp) }`.

Comment: I think the answer is then "yes": there is one document by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, in your Cloud Function, to check for each document returned by the `querySnapshot.forEach()` loop if there is at least 5 days since the user was registered (i.e. `today - registerTime > 5`), you could do as follows:

```
export const get_user_timeleft = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
            //useless part of the function...    

            const nowDate = new Date();

            querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                //Here I know that documentSnapshot.data().registerTime 
                //returns whatever is saved in the database.
                //How can I return true or false if there's been 5 
                //or more days since the user registered?

                const elapsedTime = (nowDate.getTime() - documentSnapshot.data().registerTime.getTime());

                const daysDifference = Math.floor(elapsedTime/1000/60/60/24);

                //Check that the difference is more than 5 and then act accordingly
                //It is not crystal clear from your question if there is only one document in the querySnapshot


            })

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        response.json(error);
    });

});
```

**In case you know for sure that there is only one document returned by the query** (which seems to be the case, in the light of the comments under your question), you could do:

```
export const get_user_timeleft = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
            //useless part of the function...    

            const nowDate = new Date();
            let daysDifference;

            querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
                //Here I know that documentSnapshot.data().registerTime 
                //returns whatever is saved in the database.
                //How can I return true or false if there's been 5 
                //or more days since the user registered?

                const elapsedTime = (nowDate.getTime() - documentSnapshot.data().registerTime.getTime());

                daysDifference = Math.floor(elapsedTime/1000/60/60/24);            

            });

            if (daysDifference > 5) {
                 response.send({ result: true }); 
            } else {
                 response.send({ result: false }); 
            }


    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        response.json(error);
    });

});
```

Comment: Does this `The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK` thing have any meaning? I get this warning a lot but it seems pointless.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479679/firebase-update-error-the-behavior-for-date-objects-stored-in-firestore-is-goin