# How to do Date math in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a notifications scheduling function and want to limit how frequently I send a user notifications, so need some Date math (e.g., nowDate > lastSend + 1 day). I'm finding JS support for Date math in posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344218/calculate-time-difference-within-cloud-functions) but am getting errors when trying to apply them. E.g., below attempts to add 100 minutes to `user.notificationTimestamp`

```
let whenOkayToSend: Date = user.notificationTimestamp
whenOkayToSend = whenOkayToSend + 100*60*1000
```

Give error

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'number'.
```

When I tried `getMinutes` and `setMinutes` the errors say no such functions. How do I add minutes to a Date object in cloud functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a number to a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If you want to roll the date forward, you can for example convert the date to a timestamp, do the math on that, and convert the timestamp back to a date:

```
let whenOkayToSend: Date = user.notificationTimestamp
whenOkayToSend = new Date(whenOkayToSend.getTime() + 100*60*1000)
```

Note that this has nothing to do with Cloud Functions, and would apply the same in any Node.js and regular JavaScript environment. So I recommend expanding your searches for that, for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+to+date